Perfect complexes in a family
Consider a simple normal crossings variety $X=\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_i$ over $\mathbb{C}$ where $X_i$ are smooth projectiv and a flat family $\mathcal{X}\xrightarrow{\pi}\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ with $\mathcal{X}_0=\pi^{-1} (0)\cong X$ such that $\pi$ is smooth away from $\mathcal{X}_0$. Are there references giving the relation between the perfect complex of a general fiber $\mathcal{X}_t$ and the perfect complex of the central fiber $\mathcal{X}_0=X$?
Update: I would like to explain some of the motivations of this question from homological mirror symmetry. Consider a toric Fano variety $X$ with toric boundary $\partial X$, and its mirror $Y=\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ with Landau-Ginzburg superpotential $w\colon Y\to\mathbb{C}$, pick a general fiber $w^{-1} (t)\colon = Y_t$. It's expected that there is a quasi-isomorphism of dg ($A_{\infty}$)-categories $$\mathcal{W} (Y_t)\simeq\mathrm{Coh} (\partial X).$$
Taking proper subcategory, we get the corresponding quasi-isomorphism $$\mathrm{Fuk} (Y_t)\simeq\mathrm{Perf} (\partial X),$$where $\mathrm{Fuk} (Y_t)$ refers to the ``compact Fukaya category'' of $Y_t$, consisting only of compact Lagrangians inside $Y_t$.
The Batyrev mirror construction gives a compactification of $Y_t$ into $\bar{Y}_t$ in terms of the toric data on $X$, and the expected mirror to $\bar{Y}_t$ is a smoothing of the toric boundary $\partial X$, denoted $X_r$, which is naturally a Calabi-Yau hypersurface. Let $D_t$ be the divisor at infinity of $Y_t\hookrightarrow\bar{Y}_t$, and ignoring the non-smoothness issues, we expect a mirror equivalence $$\mathrm{Fuk} (\bar{Y}_t, D_t;\kappa)\simeq\mathrm{Coh} (X_{\kappa (r)})$$where $\kappa (r)$ is supposed to be the ``mirror map'' and $\kappa$ encodes the information of the Kähler moduli. This was actually newly proved in this paper, with a little difference that in general the Fukaya category is naturally defined over the Novikov ring, so that on the mirror side we should consider varieties over the Novikov ring, which involves non-archimedean analysis, but let's not worry about this and assuming convergence of coefficients so that we can go back to the field of complex numbers.
Now since $\mathrm{Fuk} (\bar{Y}_t,D_t;\kappa)$ is a deformation of $\mathrm{Fuk} (Y_t)$ based on the construction and the corresponding work of Seidel, Sheridan and Sheridan-Smith, it's expected that there should exist some deformation of $\mathrm{Perf} (\partial X)$ into $\mathrm{Coh} (X_r)\simeq\mathrm{Perf} (X_r)$, and I'm wondering whether there're explicit descriptions of this type of deformations (from normal crossings to its smoothing) completely in the algebro-geometric side. I believe this should fit into the framework of Lowen-van den Bergh.
A little explanation of the ``relative Fukaya category'': Objects in this category are the same as the category $\mathrm{Fuk} (Y_t)$, consisting of compact Lagrangians in $Y_t$, and we deform the morphisms $CF^{\ast} (L,K)$ to encode disks with positive intersections with the divisor at infinity ("disks diverging to infinity"), where $\kappa$ refers to the formal parameter so that $\kappa^{\vec{u}}$ is in the coefficients of disks with intersection vector $\vec{u}$ with components of the divisor at infinity (which is supposed to be simple normal crossings).

What kind of relation would you expect?

@Sasha I would expect the perfect complex of the smoothing being a deformation of perfect complex of the central fiber, and the deformation is given by the perfect complex of the family $\mathcal{X}$.

Then everything depends on the precise sense of these words (what exactly do you mean by a deformation of a category?).

@Sasha I updated in the questions.
